# What pipelines permissions can be used to remove users' abilities to enable or disable pipeline agents in a specific pool?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have some users that are disabling agents when others are running jobs in the agent pool. We think they are trying to get their jobs to the top of the line.

Is there a permission we can use to remove the ability for a set of users to disable / enable agents in a specific pool?

This is the screen where you enable/disable the agents.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to agent pool and under `Security` tab

[image]

add the user or group as a reader.

[image]

Then if user tries to disable the agent it will get an error.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how you are able to set that role using the CLI or API?

Comment: I am not sure of that. You will need to go through the REST api. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0